# Apache Shiro AES encryption differs from expected output

Tags: java, encryption, shiro

I am using `AesCipherService` from Apache Shiro.

For some reason, I can't get it to work like http://aesencryption.net/.

My code is basically this:

```
String encrypt(String input) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    AesCipherService aesCipher = new AesCipherService();
    byte[] bytes = aesCipher.encrypt(input.getBytes(), "0123456789abcdef".getBytes()).getBytes();
    String aesProduct = new String(bytes);
    builder.append(aesProduct);

    byte[]   bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(builder.toString().getBytes()); 

    return new String(bytesEncoded);
}
```

If you encrypt "Hello" you will get

```
Shvvv71GB++/vULvv73vv71/Zu+/vRIc77+977+9Y33bkmrvv70SOWffqXTvv71777+977+9
```

When that site outputs

```
IM/5UIbDXWhuPz2ZFKyScQ==
```

What did I do wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may be doing Base 64 encoding more than once.  Also, that [site](http://aesencryption.net/) uses "ECB" mode, which is not the default in Cipher. So, you are seeing the difference in outputs.  It is important that encryption and decryption use same algorithm.

Below is corrected code.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.AesCipherService;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(encrypt("Hello"));
    }

    static String encrypt(String input) throws Exception {
        AesCipherService aesCipher = new AesCipherService();
        aesCipher.setModeName("ECB");
        byte[] bytes = aesCipher.encrypt(input.getBytes("UTF-8"), "0123456789abcdef".getBytes()).getBytes();
        byte[]   bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes); 
        return new String(bytesEncoded);
    }
}
```

This produces

```
xqkuF4FDmucSdb410R0HPw==
```

**NOTE:** This is not same as what [site](http://aesencryption.net/) produces for same input, however, this string can be decrypted on the [site](http://aesencryption.net/).  I am not sure what is the reason of the difference.

[image]

Comment: b64 xqkuF4FDmucSdb410R0HPw== hex c6a92e17 81439ae7 1275be35 d11d073f decrypts to ASCII "Hello" with 11 bytes of 0x0B **PCKS#5/7 padding** which real Java (JCE) does by default and I'll guess shiro does also.
b64 IM/5UIbDXWhuPz2ZFKyScQ== hex 20cff950 86c35d68 6e3f3d99 14ac9271 decrypts to ASCII "Hello" with **zero padding**.
The introductory text on that website suggests to me they use PHP crypto which is notorious for using unsafe zero padding; just search security.SE.